# Convert (in Bash) a Python list to a Bash array

Tags: python, arrays, bash, list

I have a bash script that is calling a python script like so:

```
OUTPUT=$(python /path/path/script.py attr attr attr);
```

The python script will return a data list like so:

```
[item1, item2, item3]
```

How can I convert the $OUPUT variable which is a string of the return python data list into a bash array?

I'd like to read each item in bash if possible.

Comment: I'm able to retrieve the string from python, I want to know how to turn that string into a bash array.

Comment: If you can modify the python script to change its output that will make this easier and safer for more possible output values. Otherwise you have to make assertions about what the output is allowed to have in it.

Comment: That is the problem I'm having, I'm not allowed to change the output, it was a awkward task assigned to me :(

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Add `()` and `| tr -d '[],'`:

```
OUTPUT=($(python /path/path/script.py attr attr attr | tr -d '[],'))

echo ${OUTPUT[0]}
echo ${OUTPUT[1]}
echo ${OUTPUT[2]}
echo ${OUTPUT[@]}
```

Output:

```
item1
item2
item3
item1 item2 item3
```

Comment: +1. Things will get more complicated if the array elements contain whitespace.

Comment: @glennjackman: yes, this solution is not suitable for items with whitespaces.

Comment: With bash >= 4.0 this is suitable for items with whitespaces: `mapfile -t OUTPUT < <(python /path/path/script.py attr attr attr | sed 's/[][]//g;s/, /\n/g')`

Comment: It would be helpful to show the contents of `script.py` to ensure clarity.

Answer (score 9):

You can make your script.py print a string that separates each item with spaces, which Bash will convert to an array, or you can use Bash to convert the return value of the python script into the format you want.

If you chose to print a string from your script.py you can use the following python code:

```
returnList = [1, 2, 3]
returnStr = ''
for item in returnList:
    returnStr += str(item)+' '
print(returnStr)
```

In this case, the output of the following bash script:

```
OUTPUT=$(python /path/to/script.py)
echo $OUTPUT
for i in $OUTPUT;
do
    echo $i
done
```

is:

```
1 2 3
1
2
3
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This is one of the cleanest solutions for this "issue", I've seen. Thx

Comment: Upvoted, but simpler is: `print(" ".join(returnList))`

Answer (score 4):

Bash declares arrays like this:

```
foo=(bar baz ban)
```

To convert space separated command output to an array you can therefore do this:

```
foo=($(my_command))
```

And to convert a list to a space separated string is very easy in Python:

```
' '.join(my_array)
```

If you `print` that instead of the list itself you can therefore trivially convert it to an array.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a short Python wrapper to convert the string into something more parseable by `bash`.

```
# Proxy for script.py output that includes some potential bash pitfalls
python_output="['a b', 'c*', 6]"

# Let Python output each element of the list as a separate line;
# the only thing this cannot handle is multi-line elements; workarounds
# are possible, but not worth getting into unless necessary. 
while read -r; do
    OUTPUT+=("$REPLY")
done < <(python -c 'import ast, sys
print "\n".join(str(x) for x in ast.literal_eval(sys.argv[1]))
' "$python_output")

# Verify that each element was added to the array unscathed.
for e in "${OUTPUT[@]}"; do
    echo "$e"
done
```

In `bash` 4, you can use the `readarray` command to replace the while loop:

```
readarray -t OUTPUT < <(python -c ... )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simply create a bash list from a python list in python, you can use this one-liner:

```
python -c 'print(" ".join([str(elem) for elem in [1, "l", 12]]))'
```

It gives you directly the list:

```
1 l 12
```

Note that it requires to modify the python code instead of doing this from the external bash code.