# Execute bash commands that are within a list from python

Tags: python, arrays, tuples

i got this list

```
commands = ['cd var','cd www','cd html','sudo rm -r folder']
```

I'm trying to execute one by one all the elements inside as a bash script, with no success. Do i need a for loop here?

how to achieve that?, thanks all!!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [running multiple bash commands with subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742789/running-multiple-bash-commands-with-subprocess)

Comment: You could condense the `cd` commands into one command, then use Bash's `&&` (and) operator: `os.system("cd var/www/html/ && sudo rm -r folder")`

Comment: What does Python have to do with this?  You said "execute as a bash script".

Comment: That's a wacky thing to want to do anyway. Your command is equivalent to `sudo rm -r var/www/html/folder`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete a file or folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996603/delete-a-file-or-folder)

Comment: Maybe see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950538/874188 for a number of things to look out for with subprocesses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for command in commands:
    os.system(command)
```

is one way you could do it ... although just cd'ing into a bunch of directories isnt going to have much impact

**NOTE** this will run each command in its own subshell ... so they would not remember their state (ie any directory changes or environmental variables)

if you need to run them all in one subshell than you need to chain them together with "&&"

```
os.system(" && ".join(commands)) # would run all of the commands in a single subshell
```

as noted in the comments, in general it is preferred to use subprocess module with `check_call` or one of the other variants. however in this specific instance i personally think that you are in a 6 to 1 half a dozen to the other, and `os.system` was less typing (and its gonna exist whether you are using python3.7 or python2.5 ... but in general use `subprocess` exactly which call probably depends on the version of python you are using ... there is a great description in the post linked in the comments by @triplee [why you should use subprocess instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538))

really you should reformat your commands to simply

`commands = ["sudo rm -rf var/www/html/folder"]` note that you will probably need to add your python file to your sudoers file

also Im not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish here ... but i suspect this might not be the ideal way to go about it (although it should work...)

Comment: This won't work because `cd var` will run in a subprocess, then the next command runs in the (unchanged) directory of the parent Python process.

Comment: the condition that they all run in the same subshell was not stipulated ... but i can see how the OP would  potentially desire that behaviour

Comment: No, it wasn't spelled out, and probably the OP doesn't even realize this; but this is a common enough bug with subprocesses.

Comment: Alao you should prefer `subprocess.run()` or `subprocess.check_call()` over `os.system()`; see the post I linked from another comment above.

Comment: none of the *compelling* reasons to do that apply here imho .... its really 6 to 1 half a dozen to the other ... in fact he is using commands that would require `shell=True` so its pretty extra moot ... that said in general yes... this was just less typing

Answer (score 3):

This is just a suggestion, but if your just wanting to change directories and delete folders, you could use [`os.chdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir) and [`shutil.rmtree()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree):

```
from os import chdir
from os import getcwd
from shutil import rmtree

directories = ['var','www','html','folder']

print(getcwd())
# current working directory: $PWD

for directory in directories[:-1]:
    chdir(directory)

print(getcwd())
# current working directory: $PWD/var/www/html

rmtree(directories[-1])
```

Which will `cd` three directories deep into `html`, and delelte `folder`. The current working directory changes when you call `chdir()`, as seen when you call [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd).

Answer (score 2):

```
declare -a command=("cd var","cd www","cd html","sudo rm -r folder")

## now loop through the above array
for i in "${command[@]}"
do
echo "$i"
# or do whatever with individual element of the array
done

# You can access them using echo "${arr[0]}", "${arr[1]}" also
```

Comment: this is awesome :) I think they were asking how to do it in python but this is great! thanks!

Comment: A python list can be very easily imported in to bash
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162394/convert-a-python-data-list-to-a-bash-array